# wp_remote_get fails with "Failure when receiving data from the peer"

Tags: php, wordpress, httprequest

I'm trying to get file contents of a file with this:

```
$google_fonts = (array)wp_remote_get( THEME_ADMIN_URI.'/google_fonts.txt' );
```

On `var_dump($google_fonts);` it prints this:

```
array(2) {
    ["WP_Errorerrors"]=> array(1) { 
        ["http_request_failed"]=> array(1) { 
            [0]=> string(41) "Failure when receiving data from the peer" 
        }
    }
    ["WP_Errorerror_data"]=> array(0) { }
}
```

This is the first time I see this. I'm on a support task on a foreign server and WP Installation, so I have limited access, especially to php and server settings.
Path is good, and on my server and localhost, it works fine.
File can be accessed directly in browser.

If I try to use `file_get_contents()` based on the local directory not the domain, it works.

Any ideas what's causing this?

Comment: Can you directly access that URI?

Comment: @rnevius Yes, I can.

Comment: Sounds like you're being firewalled...I'd try adding a `define('ALTERNATE_WP_CRON', true);` in your *wp_config.php*

Comment: @rnevius I did, and it doesn't help. I have edited the question, file_get_contents() does return success. Though, I would like to use wp_remote_get() since it is better practice, am I right?

Answer (score 2):

I've seen wp_remote_get() fail when the domain being requested uses CloudFlare -- something about how CloudFlare does SSL confuses wp_remote_get() and the requests error out when the SSL certs (both on the site and inside CloudFlare) appear properly configured.

Comment: You find a solution/workaround for this?  I have a site running WooCommerce in WP and 'wp_remote_get' returns a server 500 response when polling their test endpoint: http://www.woothemes.com/wc-api/product-key-api?request=ping&network=0, yet 200 responses on other urls.  the Woo url server name is listed as 'cloudflare-nginx' btw.